# When i put one DIV inside another, it doesn't copy its width and height

Tags: css, html

HTML code:

```
<div id="container>

<div id="wrapper">Some text
</div>

</div>
```

CSS code:

```
div {

position:fixed;
display:block;
}

#container {
max-width:1500px;
height:10%;
}

#wrapper {
width:50%;
height:10%;
}
```

---

Now, my wrapper and container have the same size, although you would expect that the wrapper is half the height of the container, and one tenth the height of the container. Unfortunately, they are evenly big right now. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Is the missing `"` also present in your actual html?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `max-width` to `width` on `#container` to get the width right:

```
#container {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 10%;
}
```

And you need to remove `position: fixed` and set height on `html, body` to get the percent height to work:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bGw47/2/)

(You're also missing an ending `"` in the container div, but I assumed that was a typo)

Comment: This doesn't address the height.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background-color: blue;
}

#wrapper {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```